# Where is ripple defined on Material Flat Button

Tags: android, android-appcompat

On API 21+ Flat Buttons ripple when touched. Where in AppCompat is this defined?

I can find that the ripple on Raised Buttons is defined in `drawable/v21/abc_btn_colored_material.xml`. But the only flat button drawable is defined in the base `drawables/abc_btn_borderless_material.xml` which doesn't have ripple (obviously).

So where is the ripple getting set on flat buttons?

I'm looking in appcompat-v7:23:4.0

EDIT:

I did follow the path described by Alexander Mironov but my btn_borderless_material looks like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you using the same SDK as me? As you mentioned appcompat-v7:23 I assumed that you using API 23. Final path is `PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK\platforms\android-23\data\res\drawable\btn_borderless_material.xml` on my system, you can check if it matches to your.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start our journey with AppCompat `values.xml`:

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
```

When we go to parent we have specialization with `v21` qualifier `values-v21.xml`. Here we see:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless"/>
```

Ok, that's mean that when API is 21 or higher we use Android's built-in theme. Let's go to `styles_material.xml`:

```
   <!-- Borderless ink button -->
    <style name="Widget.Material.Button.Borderless">
        <item name="background">@drawable/btn_borderless_material</item>
        <item name="stateListAnimator">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Then go to `btn_borderless_material`. And finally we have our ripple:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@id/mask"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_mtrl_shape" />
</ripple>
```

Comment: I did follow that path but ended up with a different `btn_borderless_material`. I updated my original question.